# C++ error detection in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++-2005

Coming from a different development environment (Java, mostly) I'm trying to make analogies to habits I'm used to.

I'm working with a C++ project in Visual Studio 2005, the project takes ~10 minutes to compile after changes. It seems odd that if I make a small syntactical error, I need to wait a few good minutes to get a feedback on that from the compiler, when running the entire project build.

Eclipse gave me the habit that if I make some small change I will immediately get a compiler error with an underline showing the error. Seems reasonable enough that VS should be able to do this.

[image]

Is this something I can enable in VS or do I need an external plug-in for this?

Comment: If it takes 10 minutes to compile, there is something wrong woth your project organisation or your C++ installation.

Comment: @Neil - I do not agree. This is a very big project with many dependencies.

Comment: That's what I mean - you should not have those many dependancies (or very big projects, IMHO)

Comment: @Neil - We have a project here that requires 45 minutes to build on a dual quad core with 8 GiB or RAM. When it's big, it's big. :D

Comment: I seem to be the only person round here that has heard of modular decomposition. That's what libraries are for, folks!

Comment: BTW, Visual C++ 2010 beta already includes much improved IntelliSense and error detection: http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/06/01/c-gets-squiggles.aspx

Comment: @Yuval: If you have broken up your software into reasonable small sub projects the build should not take 10 minutes. This is because you only have to build (not rebuild!) the project containing your changes to see the error! If you always build or even rebuild the whole solution you're right that it takes too much time. But this isn't necessary. Just follow Neils recommendation for breaking up into libraries.

Comment: @rstevens - I do not have this privilege. This is a project I was handed over as-is.

Comment: If you've got 300+ modules, build time will still suck. Big C++ projects will never build quickly. Using modules will still be a lot better than the alternative. As for Yuval A's last remark: get the privilege. The previous maintainer was obviously not qualified.

Comment: I have worked on a project where linking alone took >5mins. If you compiled everything from scratch, VS took ~1hr. But this was ~4MLoC with too many dependencies. But even if reduction of unnecessary dependencies would have cut the compilation time to half,  it would still have been a long compile/link cycle to wait for. Distributed compilation and incremental linking was our way out.

Comment: @Yuval A: It is perfectly fine to have a project that takes 10 minutes (or 2 hours) to compile from scratch. However, when you make just one (or several) local change and it takes 10 minutes of compilation time just to get to the point when the error gets detected by the compiler, it is strange. It is very strange. I personally have no idea how it is even possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The feature you are asking for will be available in Visual Studio 2010. [Here is a detailed link of the feature details](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/06/01/c-gets-squiggles.aspx) that will be available.

For now, as others have suggested, you can use Visual Assist which can help a little bit.

These are called Squiggles BTW.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following:

- install a plugin like Visual Assist: it will notify you about most of the errors;
- if you want to check yourself, use Ctrl-F7 to compile the file you are currently editing - in such case, you will not need to wait for all project to compile. If you are editing a header file, compile one of the .cpp files it is included in.

Comment: Ctrl-F7 is a good start, but I still need some visual feedback. I'll look at Visual Assist.

Comment: In Visual Assist you can press Alt-O to to open the related h or cpp file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, C++ is notorious for its build times. Visual Studio cannot perform on-the-fly syntax checking (in case of C++), but you can install [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) to help with that:

[image]
<sub>(source: [wholetomato.com](http://www.wholetomato.com/images/tour/fewerErrorsUnderline.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

10 minutes is quite a long time to wait, are you doing a full build every time? There are a lot of techniques you can use to speed this up, for example using precompiled headers. I try to organise my code so that I do all of my significant changes in the code file instead of the header, then just do a build of that one file (ctrl F7) to check for errors.

Answer (score 1):

You have the "error list window" that will list your errors and warnings **after compilation**. If you double click on the error it will directly go to the problematic line of code in your source. It's in the menu Display, sub menu "Other windows".

Keep in mind that compiling C++ is a much more difficult task than compiling Java, which explains the increased time.

Visual Assist X is very cool but only detects typos.

It cannot be compiled "on the fly" which explain the feature you ask is not possible. If you have a multicore machine, you can enable parallel building.

Tools -> Options -> Projects and solutions -> Generate and Execute -> maximum number of parallel compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper for C# has it. But for c++, maybe visual assist x ?

Comment: Resharper is very nice, but the built-in intellisense will immediately highlight compilation errors on C#.

Answer (score 0):

> Eclipse gave me the habit that if I make some small change I will immediately get a compiler error with an underline showing the error. Seems reasonable enough that VS should be able to do this.

Eclipse has implemented *their own* Java compiler, and run that in the background every time you type a word to be able to detect and underline errors. I don't know if I'd call that "reasonable". ;)

It's a lot of work to implement that feature, even in a simple language like Java.
In C++, where, as you've discovered, compiles may take minutes, it's harder still.

Visual Studio 2010 is going to implement this feature (again, using a separate compiler, which is much stripped down, and won't *always* provide correct results -- that's the compromise necessary to ensure that it's fast enough to compile on the fly).